# jpa create query method

Tags: java, jpa

```
public List<Double> getAllCards(int a) {
    EntityManager em = emFactory.createEntityManager();

    Query query = em.createQuery("Select u.cardNumber from Creditcard u where u.userID= :id");
    query.setParameter("id", a);
    List<Double> result = query.getResultList();
    em.close();
    return result;
}
```

This is my code for getting all the users credit cards.
This is the error message

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You have attempted to set a value of type class java.lang.Integer for parameter id with expected type of class JPA.User from query string Select u.cardNumber from Creditcard u where u.userID= :id.

In my database the cardnumber is stored as a double and the userid is stored as a int so I am confused as to why the program is telling me i need to send a jpa.user object.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `EntityManager#createQuery`, the String inside it is not SQL but JPQL. Your `userID` mapped element in `CreditCard` class is of type `User` (another class) and not the id of the user as you expect.

Probably, and just probably, the JPQL query you're looking for is:

```
Select u.cardNumber from Creditcard u where u.userID.id = :id
```

To be sure if this may be the JPQL query that solves your problem, we would need to see design of `CreditCard` and `User` classes.